# Affecting other views in Marionette

Tags: javascript, marionette

I am working in Marionette and have an accordion which we have set up so that the individual panels are templates that are called in and created by

```
var AccorionView = require(“../folder/AccordionView”);
var expandButtons = require(“../folder/expandButtons”);


var MainPage = Marionette.View.extend({

regions: {
  region: “.region”,
  button: “.buttons”
},

this.newAccordion = new AccordionView({
  header: “header goes here”,
  childView: new panelView(),
});
this.showChildView(‘region’, this.newAccordion);”
```

I am going to pull in another view with the actual Expand/Collapse All button in it, which will expand and collapse all of the accordion panels on this page. The JavaScript that would be used on this page would be

```
expandAll: function() {
  this.newAccordion.expand();
},
```

However, this function will be put into the new JavaScript view of the buttons. I am going to send the names of the accordion panels to the button view when calling it into this page, but how do I get the function on that view to influence the accordion panels on this main page?

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Backbone.Radio](https://marionettejs.com/docs/master/backbone.radio.html) in this case:

```
const Radio = require('backbone.radio');

const accorionChannel = Radio.channel('accorion');

const MainPage = Marionette.View.extend({
  // ...
  initialize() {
    accorionChannel.on('expand', function() {
      this.newAccordion.expand();
    });

    accorionChannel.on('unexpand', function() {
      this.newAccordion.unexpand();
    });
  }
  // ...
});

const WhateverView = Marionette.View.extend({
  someEventHandler() {
    accorionChannel.trigger('expand');
    // OR
    accorionChannel.trigger('unexpand');
  }
});
```

Radio channel is singleton, you can create a new one every time but it will refer to the same channel. This saves you from passing the channel variable around or having a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this one of two ways

1) With [triggers/childViewEvents](https://marionettejs.com/docs/master/events.html#child-view-events)

```js
// in expandButtons
expandButtons = Marionette.View.extend(
  triggers: {
    'click @ui.expandAll': 'expandAll'
  }
);

// in MainPage
MainPage = Marionette.View.extend({
  childViewEvents: {
    'expandAll': 'expandAll'
  },
  expandAll: function(child) {
    this.newAccordion.expand();
    // OR
    this.getChildView('region').expand();
  }
})
```

OR

2) With [Backbone.Radio](https://marionettejs.com/docs/master/backbone.radio.html)

```js
// in expandButtons
var Radio = require('Backbone.Radio');
var expandChannel = Radio.channel('expand');
var expandButtons = Marionette.View.extend({
  events: {
    'click @ui.expandAll': 'expandAll'
  },
  expandAll: function(e) {
    expandChannel.trigger('expand:all');
  }
});

// in AccordionView
var AccordionView = Marionette.View.extend({
  channelName: 'expand',
  radioEvents: {
    'expand:all': 'expand' // triggers this.expand();
  }
});
```

In this case, it might be even easier to do #2 but instead of adding the radio listener to the AccordionView, attach the listeners to the PanelView (AccordionView's `childView`). This is because AccordionView's `expand` function will likely have to [iterate each of its children like](https://marionettejs.com/docs/master/marionette.collectionviewadvanced.html#collectionview-childview-iterators-and-collection-functions):

```js
this.children.each(function(childView) {
  childView.expand();
});
```